# Redirect old domain to new domain keeping url

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, dns

We are releasing a new version of our Web app and in the process doing a branding change with a new domain also.

Both our apps are hosted in Azure.
Current App - Cloud Service
New App - Azure Website

What I want to achieve is redirect any old links from the old domain to the new domain while keeping the url portion.

Example:
User visits
https://my.currentdomain.com/any/link

and will be directed to
https://my.newdomain.io/any/link

Do I do a CNAME from currentdomain to newdomain and then a URL Rewrite in my web.config??

Thanks!

Update - I've test this locally and it does what I'm looking for. I'll just point the cname of the old domain to the new domain and this redirect should pick up the links.

```
<rule name="Redirect to new domain" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>            
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^olddomain(:\d+)?$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://my.newdomain.io/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you host your application in Azure has minimal to no impact on the solution you are going to find.

When you do such things, you usually want to also keep all the credits that you have in the search engines. And you can only achieve that if your `https://my.current.domain.com/any/link` does a `HTTP 301 Redirect Permanent` to the new location.

Depending on the size and complexity of your project this can be a trivial task or not so easy.

One option, which is valid only if you want to redirect few (like a dozen) links. You can do that directly in your Web.Config file:

```
  <location path="any/link">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://my.newdomain.io/any/link" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

This of course makes no sense when you have a bunch of links, or even a whole CMS behind the scenes. If this is the case, I would opt-in for writing a [custom HTTP Module for IIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673(v=vs.85).aspx). This module will have the sole purpose of inspecting the incoming URI and either let it further, or generate HTTP 301 redirect.

If you are using the latest and the greatest from Microsoft, the same (custom HTTP Module) can be achieved with a [custom OWIN Middleware](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/05/01/inject-custom-middleware.aspx).

If it is just domain change, all paths and query strings are to be kept, check out [this good article how can you do this with URL Rewrite under IIS](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is 100s of links. Example /Feed/{Variable} and other Controller/Action types like that. Is there a way to do a redirect for olddomain.com/*/* to newdomain.com/*/* ?

Comment: Thanks - I used that pattern redirect in the article and all links are redirecting to the new domain and keeping their query with /{R:1}

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your header file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get Current URL
    var url = window.location.href;
    // Replace domain in URL
    var newurl = url.replace("olddomain.com", "newdomain.com");
    // Redirect to new URL
    document.location = newurl;
</script>
```